# How to check if the custom field value exists from a list in JIRA using Java

Tags: java, rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

We have the following **CustomField in JIRA** named AutomatedTestSource.
When we submit a value which doesn't exist in the List, it gives an error.

How do I **check if the value exists in the custom field list** and then enter it.

Im using Jira **REST Client 1.0** jar.

This is how I set the value for custom field,

```
             Map<String, Object> mapValues = new HashMap<>();
             mapValues.put("value", automatedTestSource);
             ComplexIssueInputFieldValue fieldValue = new ComplexIssueInputFieldValue(mapValues);
             issueBuilder.setFieldValue("customfield_12940", fieldValue);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic answer would be to use a try/except clause - maybe something like:

```
try:
    issueBuilder.setFieldValue("customfield_12940", fieldValue);
except (ValueError, AttributeError) as e:
    log.error("Bogus fieldValue {0}".format(fieldValue))
    # do something else here
```

Note you may need to capture one or more python [python exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) in the except clause.